# Can't install a Perl module from CPAN

Tags: perl, installation

Trying to run a Perl script on Linux, I got an error: "Can't locate Devel/GlobalDestruction.pm"

So, I ran CPAN shell and tried to install it:

```
$ perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan> install Devel::GlobalDestruction
```

But, unfortunately, got an error:

```
...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite Devel::GlobalDestruction::XS 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Sub::Exporter::Progressive 0.001011 not found.
Only one of PREFIX or INSTALL_BASE can be given.  Not both.
No 'Makefile' created  HAARG/Devel-GlobalDestruction-0.13.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/home/onlinetv/perl/usr -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 HAARG/Devel-GlobalDestruction-0.13.tar.gz    : writemakefile NO -- No 'Makefile' created
```

Probably, something is wrong here: "Only one of PREFIX or INSTALL_BASE can be given.  Not both."

But I don't know, how to fix it.

### Update

`>o conf` outputs the following:

```
make_arg           [PREFIX=/home/onlinetv/perl/usr]
make_install_arg   []
make_install_make_command undef
makepl_arg         [PREFIX=/home/onlinetv/perl/usr]
mbuild_install_build_command [./Build]
mbuildpl_arg       [PREFIX=/home/onlinetv/perl/usr]
```

I printed only lines, related to PREFIX

```
-bash-3.2$ set | grep ^PERL
PERL5LIB=/home/onlinetv/perl5/lib/perl5
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=/home/onlinetv/perl5
PERL_MB_OPT='--install_base "/home/onlinetv/perl5"'
PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=/home/onlinetv/perl5
```

Comment: Well, where is `PREFIX=/home/onlinetv/perl/usr` coming from?

Comment: @SinanÜnür Where can I find this? I don't have .bashrc or bash_profile files in my home dir. And it's not shown in "perl -V".

Comment: @Borodin There is no ~/.profile file. So, nothing is there. I tried to run `unset PREFIX`, then ran cpan shell. But the error is still there.

Comment: Provide the output of `o conf` from with the cpan shell.  There are too says of interest.  One starts with `mbuild`. I can't remember the other but it's similar. Also provide output of `set | grep ^PERL` from your command shell

Comment: SU&Bo, PREFIX and INSTALL_BASE are Makefile.PL args, not env vars

Comment: @ikegami I updated the question, printing the necessary lines

Comment: `make_arg` should be blank, but it might not be causing any problems.

Comment: You can see the actual problem now, right? It's picking up one setting from the env and the other from `cpan`. Get rid of the one you don't want

Comment: @ikegami Should I run the command: "unset PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT" in bash?

Comment: @ikegami Could you please give an answer, how to unset those variables. I ran `"unset PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT`, then "export PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT"  in bash. But the error is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cpan` is configured to provide one setting to `Makefile.PL`, and `Makefile.PL` is picking up a conflicting setting from the environment.

It looks like you use local::lib, which uses the `INSTALL_BASE` paradigm. As such, simply tell `cpan` to stop specifying `PREFIX`. From within the `cpan` shell,

```
o conf makepl_arg ''
o conf mbuildpl_arg ''
o conf commit
```

At the same time, fix the nonsense value for `make_arg`.

```
o conf make_arg ''
o conf commit
```

Answer (score 0):

cpan is nice tool when you have many time and account for StackOverflow. Please install App::cpanminus and use cpanm instead.

```
curl -L https://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo App::cpanminus
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access root on that machine. Is it possible to install it locally for my user?

Comment: If you messed cpanm's configuration in the same way, you get the same result.

Comment: Looks like this is an alternative (or additional) CPAN source?

Doesn't look particularly harmful, but not keen on answers that suggest "pipe this random thing from the internet" ;)

Answer (score -1):

To address this error:

**Trying to run a Perl script on Linux, I got an error: "Can't locate Devel/GlobalDestruction.pm”**

### cpanm

I use [cpanm](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.7033/lib/App/cpanminus.pm) from Tatsuhiko Miyagawa.

Following the personal install guidelines in that document, this next section will install **cpanm** into **~/bin**, which needs to be in your **PATH**.

```
cd ~/bin
curl -L https://cpanmin.us/ -o cpanm
chmod +x cpanm
which cpanm
```

Now use **cpanm** to install the missing library in a directory named **local** inside a given directory holding the original script, such as **dir**:

```
cd <dir>
cpanm -L local Devel::GlobalDestruction
```

To include the package installed in that directory,

- **use FindBin** to locate the current local directory, and
- **use lib** to locate your recently installed files.

Here is the code to add to the original script, located in **dir**

```
use FindBin qw( $Bin );
use lib “$Bin/local/lib/perl5”;
```

The **cpanm** code recursively installs all dependencies. In my session I got these two:

```
cpanm -L local Devel::GlobalDestruction
--> Working on Devel::GlobalDestruction
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/H/HA/HAARG/Devel-GlobalDestruction-0.13.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Devel-GlobalDestruction-0.13 ... OK
==> Found dependencies: Sub::Exporter::Progressive
--> Working on Sub::Exporter::Progressive
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/F/FR/FREW/Sub-Exporter-Progressive-0.001011.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Sub-Exporter-Progressive-0.001011 ... OK
Building and testing Sub-Exporter-Progressive-0.001011 ... OK
Successfully installed Sub-Exporter-Progressive-0.001011
Building and testing Devel-GlobalDestruction-0.13 ... OK
Successfully installed Devel-GlobalDestruction-0.13
2 distributions installed
```

---

### As a small variation of the above

Change the **cpanm** argument from upper L **[-L]** to lower l **[-l]** to see if their is a  difference in being complete, or not in the package dependency set.

Delete the **local** directory between those attempts to ensure that the packages installed are minimal.

---

### A test

As an example use of the above, here is the modification to the 03_minusc.t test case that finds the new libraries in the directory into which I downloaded the libraries above into a directory named **local**:

The link with the original test:

http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/HAARG/Devel-GlobalDestruction-0.13/t/03_minusc.t

Here is the modification to the code:

```
use FindBin qw( $Bin );
use lib "$Bin/local/lib/perl5";
use Devel::GlobalDestruction;
```

Here is the output:

```
1..3
ok - Test properly running under minus-c
ok - BEGIN is not GD with -c
./test.pl syntax OK
ok - Final cleanup object destruction properly in GD
```

After reading Sinan’s post, I think my perl, used below, /opt/local/bin/perl, should be changed to the one he suggested **/home/onlinetv/perl/bin/perl**

Here is the test code with the modification:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/perl

BEGIN {
  if ($ENV{DEVEL_GLOBALDESTRUCTION_PP_TEST}) {
    unshift @INC, sub {
      die 'no XS' if $_[1] eq 'Devel/GlobalDestruction/XS.pm';
    };
  }
}

{
  package Test::Scope::Guard;
  sub new { my ($class, $code) = @_; bless [$code], $class; }
  sub DESTROY { my $self = shift; $self->[0]->() }
}

sub ok ($$) {
  print "not " if !$_[0];
  print "ok";
  print " - $_[1]" if defined $_[1];
  print "\n";
  !!$_[0]
}

BEGIN {
  require B;
  B::minus_c();

  print "1..3\n";
  ok( $^C, "Test properly running under minus-c" );
}

use FindBin qw( $Bin );
use lib "$Bin/local/lib/perl5";
use Devel::GlobalDestruction;

BEGIN {
    ok !in_global_destruction(), "BEGIN is not GD with -c";
}

our $foo;
BEGIN {
  $foo = Test::Scope::Guard->new( sub {
    ok( in_global_destruction(), "Final cleanup object destruction properly in GD" ) or do {
      require POSIX;
      POSIX::_exit(1);
    };
  });
}
```